# Vaadin 24.3.7 Spring Boot (Version 3.2.4) / Security Remember-Me Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

Good day,
Who of you has ever developed Remember-Me Authentication with Vaadin (version 24.3.x) and Spring Boot (version 3.2.4)?

I'm currently using the Vaadin login and a user database.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration

public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.png")).permitAll());

    // Icons from the line-awesome addon
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/line-awesome/**/*.svg")).permitAll());

    super.configure(http);
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
}
```

The old rememberMe() is deprecated.

Comment: This is the documentation of the new Spring Security. How does your configuration currently look like?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/rememberme.html#_tokenbasedremembermeservices

Comment: This is my entire configuration. Consisting of: * Vaddin LoginView * Component AuthenticatedUser * SecurityConfiguration  * Service UserDetailsServiceImpl. What else would you like to see?

Comment: I don't see any remember me configuration

Comment: That's exactly my problem. How do I do that? I've already tried a lot. The obligated confectionery comes from Vaadin Start!

Comment: Did you check the documentation in the link I've sent you?